# How can we set the block size in hadoop specific to each file?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

for example if my input fie has 500MB i want this to split  250MB each, if my input file is 600MB block size should be 300MB

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading files into hdfs you can put with dfs.blocksize oprtion, you can calculate parameter in a shell depending on size.

```
hdfs dfs -D dfs.blocksize=268435456 -put myfile /some/hdfs/location
```

If you already have files in HDFS and want to change it's block size, you need to rewrite it.

(1) move file to tmp location:

```
 hdfs dfs -mv /some/hdfs/location/myfile /tmp
```

(2) Copy it back with `-D dfs.blocksize=268435456`

```
hdfs dfs -D dfs.blocksize=268435456 -cp /tmp/myfile /some/hdfs/location
```